# Windows Phone 8, Overwriting old app?

Tags: c#, windows

I could have sworn in WP7 whenever you deployed your application it overwrote the previous version. However it seems that it no longer does that? Is there a setting to turn that back on, or do I have to keep deleting the app before I deploy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, deploying to the phone will do an in-place update (keeping all isolated storage, very similar to an actual store update) unless it detects a clean-rebuild has been performed or some other metadata has changed (such as the app ID).

So if you are seeing it do an incremental-deploy, that is normal.  If you want it to do a clean reinstall, then do a clean-rebuild from visual studio (or just uninstall it from the phone before deploying again).